# Different behaviour at compile time while implementing generic class from Idisposable?

Tags: c#, .net, generics, idisposable

Why there is a change in behaviour in case of following codes

```
public class Repository<T> : IRepository<T> where T : BaseEntity, IDisposable
```

And

```
public class Repository<T> : IDisposable, IRepository<T> where T : BaseEntity
```

If I leave the implementation class empty, In above case it doesn't want me to implement Dispose() method. However, In below there is a need to implement Dispose() method. 
Below is complete test code as:

```
public interface Itest<T> where T: testA{ }
public class testA { }
public class test2<T> : Itest<T> where T : testA,IDisposable{ } //successfully compiled
public class test3<T> : IDisposable, Itest<T> where T : testA { }//Failed compiled : need to implement Dispose()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you have

```
public class Repository<T> : IRepository<T> where T : BaseEntity, IDisposable
```

Then `T` must implement `IDisposable`.

When you have

```
public class Repository<T> : IDisposable, IRepository<T> where T : BaseEntity
```

Then `Repository` must implement `IDisposable`.

When you want to create an instance of `test2<T>` you should provide a generic parameter which is derived from `testA` and implements `IDisposable`.

Comment: I didn't provide implementation of IDisposable in BaseEntity than why still its compiled successfully. It should ask me to provide Dispose() method within BaseEntity class but its compile happily.

Comment: When you want to create an instance of `test2<T>` you should provide a generic parameter which is derived from `testA` and implements `IDisposable`. @NomiAli

Answer (score 1):

In the first code sample, the `T` must implement `IDisposable`. In the second code sample, the `Repository` itself must implement `IDisposable`.